# Input not terminating because of a comment

Tags: c++, scanf

This cpp code is not terminating. I have tried the code by various inputs but this is not terminating.I think there is a bug in the 52th line, when I comment the 52 line than the code is working fine.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
// binary search for larger elements
using namespace std;
vector <int > q;


// bsearch value uses hte 


#define bvector q // just define these values to use them in your functin
#define VALUE(x) bvector[x]

int b_search(int value){
int low=0,high=bvector.size(),mid;
    mid=(low+high)/2;
    cout << "In the bsearch";
    while(low<high)
    {
            if(VALUE(mid)==value)
                    return mid;
            else if(VALUE(mid)>value)//                      
                    high=mid;
            else if(VALUE(mid)<value)        
                   low=mid+1; 
    }

    if(VALUE(low)>value)
            return low;
    return -1;                
}

int main(){
int i;

    for(scanf("%d",&i);i;scanf("%d",&i))
            q.push_back(i); // this is for taking input in the vectot

sort(q.begin(),q.end());                

    for(i=0;i<q.size();i++)
            printf("%d ",q[i]);// for printing the sorted

            int j;
            printf("Enter the elements you want to search");

            int x;
            scanf("%d",&x);
 // BUG is present in this lines
            cout <<"This is the end of scanf";// if this line is commented then the 54th line is not reached

            j=b_search(x);
          printf("%d ",j);
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement : mid=(low+high)/2; is a bit misplaced. It should be inside the while loop.
This is probably what is causing an infinite loop.